# Javascript tooltips without attaching to html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I am creating a web page using the ammap library to display a world map. I need to pop up a tooltip when the user clicks a country in order to display some links etc which the user can interact with for that specific country. Ammap gives me an "onclick" event, in which I can grab all the info I need to put in the tooltip - but I can't figure out exactly how to do what I want.

I have looked at the tooltipster library, but it seems the tooltips need to be attached to an element on the page which I can't do because the map is created by the ammap library.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Edit:

The event I implement for when a map area is clicked is:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
});
```

Comment: Could you share the code of that `onclick` event provided by this library

Answer (score 1):

For tooltips, I like to use a `display:none;` html element and for the object's onclick event, simply grab the element's offset, set the tooltip's `display:block;` and adjust its offsets near the clicked object.

```
<div id='tooltip'>tooltip</div>
```

In the css(change the z-index if needed):

```
display:none;
```

This all depends on the browser/client. Here's an example of what the javascript function looks like:

```
function tooltip(placeholder) {
var top = placeholder.offsetTop - 16;
var left = placeholder.offsetLeft + 16;
document.getElementById('tooltip').style.top = top;
document.getElementById('tooltip').style.left = left;
document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display="block";
}
```

For this example, you'll also need a onmouseout event to set the tooltip's display back to none.

I don't think this is the most efficient example, however it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I built a little example so you can see how to handle a tooltip on an element click event. I'm not quite familiar with the mentioned library but since the logic is similar, copy-paste the inner part of the snippet below within the given method

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
    // place the snippet below in here ...          
});`
```

and give it a try.

JavaScript.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (target.className == 'killer') return false;

    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = 'tooltip';
    div.innerHTML = 'This is a content within tooltip.';
    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.className = 'killer';
    span.innerHTML = 'X';
    span.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    };
    div.appendChild(span);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.style.left = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + 'px';
    div.style.top = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 'px'; 

}, false);
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
  background-color:#555;
  width:200px;height:50px;
  z-index:99999;
  position:absolute;
}  

.killer {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#555;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is a working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xizufubi/1/edit?html,js,output) so you may play around :)